# Movie explorer ( ALT + F3 ) in Flash CC. Is it removed now?

Tags: flash, flash-cc

Does anyone know, how to get movie explorer in Flash CC. It used to appear from windows menu, or Alt+F3. But i cannot find it in Flash CC. Is there any way to get it. Or is it removed in new version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It's removed. There is complete list of all removed features https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/190/869861

Answer (score 0):

You can find an equivalence of the Movie Explorer in the left side of the Actions panel (drag the left border of the Actions panel to the right).

Still it is not the Movie Explorer we are used to, but it's better than nothing.